# Second monitor looks distorted

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, lenovo, hdmi, monitor

I have attached an image of what I see.

My mouse seems to be pictured fine but everything else is distorted for some reason.

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general so I am not sure on how to approach this.

The second monitor is connected with an HDMI cable if that is important

[photo of monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVSfi.jpg)

Update: I just fixed the display settings on the second monitor

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am glad that you solved the problem. This is a question answer site, where problems are posed as questions and the solutions are provided as answers. If you think the solution to your question is trivial, then please delete the question. Otherwise please write your own answer by clicking on the button below. Once you have answered the question, accept your answer as the correct one by clicking on the grey check mark and turn it green. This will help others. Please don't put SOLVED in the title and the solution within the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome to ask Ubuntu**. 2 things, check the physical components are fine. Try using another device or another cable to be sure it isn't something wrong with them. I had have some problems with my monitor time ago not because the software (I tried with Windows too), but because the VGA receptor of the 2nd Screen was loose and a bit stuck inside.
If this isn't the case, more info about the installation and version would be useful.
**Edit:** I've just read you already solved the problem by changing the monitor settings. So this may be a bit redundant