# Second monitor distorted image

Tags: hardware

I just installed Ubuntu's latest version (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) on my laptop (an ASUS TUF Gaming laptop) as a dual boot with Windows 10. When I try to use my second monitor, the image gets all distorted and I can't see anything except my mouse pointer.

I've tried to search the internet for a fix, but the only thread I was able to find where the issue was similar to mine, the creator of the thread just said he fixed it by changing the settings, giving no instructions or explaining what he actually did to fix it. ([Second monitor looks distorted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315383/second-monitor-looks-distorted))

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? How can I fix that? I already tried a bunch of different settings on my "display settings" but nothing worked.

I attached a photo of how my second monitor looks like for reference.

I am sure it's not a hardware issue, because I use the exact same monitor cable and port to boot with Windows and it works with no problems.

EDIT: I am connecting via HDMI cable, the laptop is Asus TUF Gaming FX505DV-PB74.

Monitor is LG 29WL500

[image]

Comment: Please accept the edits and then [edit] it yourself and add the specific Ubuntu release/version and hardware specifications.

Comment: Test your hardware with the REAL latest version of Ubuntu: Use the "Try Ubuntu" environment of a 21.10 LiveUSB (or 22.04 pre-release LiveUSB).